# Java snippet output not understood, probably related to polymorphism

Tags: java, polymorphism

I was wondering why this bit of Java yields 2, and not 3 :

```
public class Test {
    private static class A {
        int f(A a) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    private static class B extends A {
        int f(A a) {
            return 2;
        }
        int f(B b) {
            return 3;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] astrArgs) {
        A ab = new B();
        B b = new B();

        System.out.println( ab.f(b) );  
    }
}
```

I came across this in a test question, and couldn't get the logic behind it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *compile-time* type of `ab` is just `A`. Therefore, when the compiler sees this expression:

```
ab.f(b)
```

... it *only* considers method signatures declared on `A` and its superclasses (just `Object` in this case).

So, the compiler makes the decision to call the method with the signature `f(A a)`.

Now at *execution* time, the VM chooses which *implementation* of that signature to execute based on the execution-time type of the target of the method call, which is `B`.

`B` overrides `f(A a)`, so that overriding implementation is called - and returns 2.

Basically, *overloading* is determined at compile-time to work out what method signature to call based on the compile-time types of both the target of the call and the arguments, and *overriding* is determined at execution-time to work out the exact implementation to execute based on the execution-time type of the target object.

Comment: Basically, OP should by now know what results the following expressions yield: `((B)ab).f(b)`, `b.f(ab)` and `b.f((B)ab)`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, ab is of type A, but instantiated as B. A only knows method

```
int f(A a) {
  return 1;
}
```

b is of type A, so it is valid. B overrides int f(A a), so this method is used.

```
int f(A a) {
    return 2;
}
```

Hope that helps.